# Definition of the ln function with integral

Tags: integration, logarithms

I'm trying to prove that the following function is actually the ln function. Let $F:(0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is derivable at $x = 1$, and $F(xy) = F(x) + F(y)$ for every $x,y > 0$. I'm trying to prove that F is derivable for every $x>0$, and to give a formula for $F'(x)$, so I could use the Fundemtnal Theorem of Calculus. I know it involves a trick with $F(xy) = F(x) + F(y)$. I've tried playing with $F(1) = F(x) \cdot F(1/x)$, but didn't get anywhere.

Comment: What definition of $\ln$ are you using?

Comment: @DHMO I could use either that ln(x) is the integral of 1/x for positive x, or  $ln(x) = \int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}dt$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{array}{rcl}
F(xy) &=& F(x) + F(y) \\
F(1) &=& F(1) + F(1) \\
F(1) &=& 0 \\
\end{array}$

Since the function is differentiable at $x=1$:

$\begin{array}{cl}
& F'(1) \\
=& \displaystyle \lim_{h\to0} \frac {F(1+h)-F(1)} {h}\\
=& \displaystyle \lim_{h\to0} \frac {F(1+h)} {h}\\
=& \displaystyle C\\
\end{array}$

where $C = F'(1)$.

Then:

$\begin{array}{cl}
& \dfrac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} F(x) \\
=& \displaystyle \lim_{h\to0} \frac {F(x+h)-F(x)} {h}\\
=& \displaystyle \lim_{h\to0} \frac {F\left(1+\frac hx\right)} {h}\\
=& \displaystyle \lim_{u\to0} \frac {F\left(1+u\right)} {ux}\\
=& \displaystyle \frac1x \lim_{u\to0} \frac {F\left(1+u\right)} {u}\\
=& \displaystyle \frac1x C\\
\end{array}$

where $u=\dfrac hx$.

Comment: Why does $\lim{h \to 0} \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h} = \lim{h \to 0} \frac{F(1+\frac{h}{x}}{h}$

Comment: Because $F(x+h) - F(x) = F \left(\frac{x+h}x\right)$